How do I compile code that uses both Physac and Raylib, which both define Vector2 struct?
If I include these two libraries, like this:
#include "raylib.h"
#include "physac.h"
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}

And compile using:
C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/mingw32-make.exe RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib PROJECT_NAME=main OBJS=main.c physac.h BUILD_MODE=DEBUG 

gcc -o main main.c physac.h -Wall -std=c99 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -g -O0 C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.rc.data -Wl,--subsystem,windows -I. -IC:/raylib/raylib/src -IC:/raylib/raylib/src/external -L. -LC:/raylib/raylib/src -LC:/raylib/raylib/src -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP

Then I get:
physac.h:158:5: error: unknown type name 'Vector2'
  158 |     Vector2 normals[PHYSAC_MAX_VERTICES];   // Polygon vertex normals vectors

So I define PHYSAC_STANDALONE to add Vector2 to the physac.h.  But then I get a redefinition error:
physac.h:119:16: error: redefinition of 'struct Vector2'
  119 | typedef struct Vector2
      |                ^~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:1:
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:204:16: note: originally defined here
  204 | typedef struct Vector2 {
      |                ^~~~~~~
physac.h:123:3: error: conflicting types for 'Vector2'; have 'struct Vector2'
  123 | } Vector2;

How can I convince these two libraries to play nicely together?

Vector2 and struct Vector2 are different things. You say “I add Vector2 to the physac.h by defining PHYSAC_STANDALONE”, and it seems that adding a #define for PHYSAC_STANDALONE changed some conditional compilation to cause a definition of struct Vector2 to be included in code that already had such a definition. That explains why you got an error about a redefinition. And of course defining struct Vector2 does nothing to provide a definition of Vector2. The code shown in the question is inadequate to see why you do not have a definition of Vector2.

@EricPostpischil https://pastebin.com/wUc4VYy7
isnt this declaring the literal same thing in raylib.h https://pastebin.com/UbB34FU1

Edit the question to provide a [mre] directly in the question. Not in comments and not in external sites.

Issue is reproducible with literally empty main function body. I dont know how can I provide an MRE.

I also provided the linker and compiler commands, arguments, Physac header. I dont know how can I provide the Raylib.

Copy the headers into main.c, then delete everything not needed to reproduce the problem. You should end up with just a few lines declaring struct Vector2 and Vector2, at which point it will likely be obvious what the problem is.

Okay but. How this will down the problem. Both PHYSAC and Raylib have a Vector 2 structs, they both declare the struct in same way, and they dont work with the steps I just explained in post. Yes I can copy paste headers into main.c, delete code until no problem, but we know what is the problem. There is 2 same structs in seperate headers that dont work in a way or another

@Caner - So you have identified the problem - you just cannot have two different structs with the same name. The only solution is not to do that. There are no tricks to allow duplicates.

You would not normally list physac.h on the GCC command line — header files do not normally contain definitions (though (static) inline functions alter that calculus) but just declarations.  What happens if you drop that from the command line?

If your problem is how to use two different libraries that provide conflicting interfaces, you should rewrite the post to state that. You may have to rewrite your program to use the different libraries in different modules.

Is the solution as simple astypedef struct Vector2 Vector2; before including <physac.h>, or does it need a different Vector2 type to that provided in Raylib?

You should report a bug to both of those libraries for not prefixing their stuff with the library name. Until they fix it, isolate one of the libraries into its own translation unit (include it in a single .c file, provide your own wrappers for it, and don't include the other library in the same file).

@HolyBlackCat I suppose the two are related and normally used together ("#define PHYSAC_STANDALONE *       Avoid raylib.h header inclusion in this file." from https://github.com/victorfisac/Physac/blob/master/src/physac.h

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I stand corrected. :) But still not nice to have an unprefixed type.

@HolyBlackCat I agree, of course. I had the same hunch when I saw the question and wanted to suggest a renaming hack with some judiciously placed #defines.

I have zero knowledge of the libraries and headers involved, but when I look at them, I see that raylib.h defines both struct Vector2 and a typedef Vector2 (that's possible because in C, struct "tags" (i.e., names) live in a distinct namespace from anything else).
physac.h defines that struct and typedef only if PHYSAC_STANDALONE is defined; as the comment on top of the file says, this is meant for cases when raylib.h is not included.
That makes sense: In that case, raylib.h's definition would be missing, and the type would be unknown. That's exactly the error you get the first time around. But why this typedef was not seen when you compiled without the PHYSAC_STANDALONE define I don't know. Did you change the include order in main.c? The Vector2 definition in raylib.h does not seem conditional to another define, afaics.
But in the compile run when you defined PHYSAC_STANDALONE, the typedef in raylib.h was seen, and consequently, the second (re-) definition caused an error. From what I see, your program should compile now as soon as you remove that define.

The subsequent issue you mentioned in the comments is a link issue: The declaration is visible, the compiler is happy, but the implementation of the declared function(s) is not found by the linker.
As discussed in the comments, the implementation is in the physac.h header; there is no library to link against or separate source file to compile. In a way, you turn one of your own source files into that library source file by including the header with the implementation in it. But because headers are included by several source files in a project, the implementation in that header must be suppressed in all included instances but one, lest the linker complain about multiple symbol definitions errors. This "expose implementation only once" is "manually" controlled by the programmer through another define, PHYSAC_IMPLEMENTATION. In exactly one of your source files, there should be a line
#define PHYSAC_IMPLEMENTATION

before the # include "physac.h line.
Alternatively, if I read the header right, one could always define PHYSAC_IMPLEMENTATION and PHYSAC_STATIC at the same time, making all functions static. That way, no symbols would be visible outside the source files that include physac.h, avoiding any linker issues, at the cost of larger code size because the implementation is present in every using source file (which will at this scale not matter at all on a PC).

Actually no, I still cannot compile. Worked on first time, BUT HEEEEEY IT IS C TIME.

I can now compile the two headers, can compile my own code, but now my own code cant see any module declarations from the physac.h. undefined reference to CreatePhysicsBodyRectangle, etc. but I dont get any error of "redefinition" or "cant find header".

@Caner-sagopaninsagkolu OK, that's a link error. The code sees the declarations, the compiler produces the proper calls, but the linker cannot resolve them. You need to add the libraries or .c files from physac which contain the implementations to your project. Hint: RTFM ;-).

OK, this is weird: The function definition is in the physac.h header. Does the code using the function include the header?

uhhh https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/196752/cant-compile-raylib-project-with-physac, turns out its librarys decision to make it like that. thanks for help on the compile issue btw

@Caner-sagopaninsagkolu Ah yes, I didn't see the dependency on PHYSAC_IMPLEMENTATION. Of course the proper way to activate the implementation is by defining PHYSAC_IMPLEMENTATION in (one of) your own source files (the header should not be touched).
